# Is it okay/normal to have two versions of VC++ 2013 redistributable installed?

Tags: windows-10

I'm having trouble installing the latest AMD Radeon Crimson driver on Windows 10 (there's a surprise) and one article talks about repairing VC++ redistributables.

On my new clean install of Windows 10 with lots of 3rd party apps installed, there are two versions of VC++ 2013 redistributable installed: 12.0.21005 and 12.0.30501

Is this okay/normal? Kind of expected there to be only one.

UPDATE:

Interesting - repairing the installation removes the older version.

Comment: Its actually to be expected.  Each program that uses VC++ references a specific version of the .dll

Comment: @Ramhound are different versions of same "year" vcredists installed side by side?I guess they _should_ but ! when I look into `System32` I can see all the DLLs names like msvcp140.dll, these do not employ any DLL name collision avoidance, so what if latest installed version overrides all the DLLs?

Comment: "are different versions of same "year" vcredists installed side by side?" - they can be.  "so what if latest installed version overrides all the DLLs?" - This isn't a concern in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer here is "no, it's not normal" and is causing this quirk with the AMD driver. As I said, repairing the installation gets rid of the duplicate. Some quirk I guess of rebuilding a new computer rapidly with lots of installs and maybe not enough reboots.